# Tensorflow JS first prediction delay

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

Once I have loaded in a TensorflowJS model successfully, the first prediction always has a 1-2 second delay. This only occurs for the VERY first prediction globally. Say I have 2 models and I predict with `model 1` and then with `model 2`, I will get the delay on the first prediction with `model 1` but NOT with `model 2`s first prediction.

```
const prediction = model.predict(X[m][i]).dataSync()[0]
```

I am creating all my input tensors before I predict, so the delay must be coming exclusively from the prediction component. I assume there is some sort of initialization that's taking place. How can I remove the delay/initialize before first prediction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The very first prediction has to initialized the weights on the backend. A warmup of the model is often recommanded to prevent the delay during first prediction. A warmup is just a prediction with a dummy data such as `tf.ones` of `tf.random`. The output of such a prediction is of no importance. But making such a prediction makes all the tensors of weigths to be initialized making the model ready - faster - for the next predictions.

```js
const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(modelUrl);

// Warmup the model before using real data.
const warmupResult = model.predict(tf.zeros(inputShape));
warmupResult.dataSync(); // we don't care about the result
warmupResult.dispose();

// Now we can use the model for real predictions
// The second predict() will be much faster
const result = model.predict(userData);
```

Comment: Damn, I was hoping there might be a more elegant solution, perhaps an "initialise" method or something. But this does the trick, thanks!